# Flash: Identical movieclips shifting coordinates

Tags: flash

I have a few movieclips with many child MCs, the only difference between these is some static text. However the instances of these movieclips are showing wierd behaviour and shifting a pixel here and a pixel there even though the child MCs are the same movieclips in each.

Anyone know why this would happen or a fix for this?

They are not bitmap cached.

Comment: Is everything positioned on whole (int) pixel values? Having a float for a positioning value can give erratic results.

Comment: Thanks that helped somewhat, still some shifting but a lot less.